# Flex Framework RSL - Specifying location at runtime

Tags: apache-flex, runtime, rsl

Can anyone tell me if the following is possible and if so, how I would set it up…

I have a Flex(3.3) web app which makes use of the Framework RSL. It currently loads the rsl from a location I have specified when compiling the app.

However, for reasons I won't explain, I need to be able to specify the location of the Framework RSL at runtime. Obviously it will be the same RSL that I compiled against, its just that I need to be able to feed in this location when the app is run, not when it is compiled.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general you can't.

same question was asked at flex forums.

complete answer:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/2172260#2172260